# Add HTML page in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel-5

Is it necessary to use blade file in laravel or we can add .html page for UI purpose and if yes then how to do this.

This sounds like a stupid question, but still I want to know about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML file but it should be a .php file. Like-

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/greeting.php -->

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

You have this greeting.php file of view show you can call this in your controller and pass values like the following.

```
return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
```

Comment: Can we call this through routes.php file of laravel?

Comment: We can use it as we use .blade.php file

Comment: You can call it through routes also like `Route::get('/', function ()    {
    return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
});`